# How to load data without blocking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, tornado, template-engine

I want to load items from a database in my template. This proccess of loading can take some seconds, so I want to display the page before the proccess is done.

```
{% for item in get_items() %}
    <div> ... </div>
{% end %}
```

How can I load this data without blocking the page?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be two views: the view that's tied to your URL which just shows the "wrapper" around your actual data and has an HTML element in it like:

```
<div id="my-content">(loading data)</div>
```

And, assuming you use jQuery, something like:

```
<script>
    $("#my-content").load("/path/to/view/that/provides/data");
</script>
```

And then have a second view wired to that URL. This should return *just* the formatted HTML of the data itself (so possibly just that table or however you're presenting it).

Of course, you can also do this not by having the second view provide formatted HTML; you could have it produce JSON or XML or some more data-y format and then format *that* with Javascript. For some cases, that can be more efficient.

If you're not using jQuery, look up how to do a simple "fill this item with the response of this URL done via AJAX" call in whatever framework you do use--or you can do this in raw Javascript too, though somewhat more verbosely.

Comment: uhm.. who will generate the template? this can't work?

Answer (score -1):

Load the page without them, then add them in via a separate Ajax call.